# Automatically Populating TextBoxes of a software from another vendor from my DB?

Tags: .net

I have a software which I will be using. The software has a number of textboxes and I cannot get an access to the code. How can I automatically populate these textboxes through my own databases?

So for example I have a win form of another vendor which has textfield of:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Address

Now I want to populate these textboxes from my own database. Is there anyway to do it?

Thank You!

Comment: someone please answer this asap

Comment: more information please!

Answer (score 0):

without know what software and whether it supports an API,  my suggestion would be to contact the manufacturer of the product first. If that fails then you have to consider using reflection and code injection. That may not be allowed in your license. Check carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly is in .NET, and the form and its fields are public, you can just reference the assembly in your program, new up the form in question, and set its fields, then call whatever behavior you need. If the assembly is unmanaged, but registered for COM, you can do much the same thing.

If the program hides its internals and doesn't play well via COM, you'll have to get creative with GDI and other unmanaged hooks. You can get the handle of the window and interrogate its children to find the fields you need, then set their values. This is extremely messy to do in an unmanaged way, so I would encourage you to explore any other option you have.